# Surrogate model data requirements

Tags: regression, experiment-design, surrogate

I am trying to undersand how to approach the development of a surrogate model to investigate the associated uncertainty when predicting late arrival times. I.e there is an, to me, agnostic and relatively complex model that makes predictions of arrival times. I am going to try to evaluate the associated uncertainty of these model predictions. I will approach it as a regression problem.

I will have access to the model predictions and the actual outcomes, but I am uncertain what parameters are required to create a surrogate model. I've read [here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/global.html#theory-4) that the data of the surrogate model needs to follow the same distribution, but in terms of input parameters what is required then? Do I need all? Does it suffice with a few of them?

If it matters, my approach is that of a statistical POV rather than an engineering POV.

Comment: oftentimes, we'll decide on a range of allowable values for each input parameter: $x_i\in[a_i,b_i]$. Then, we'll do our best to sample within that range. Uniformly at random is pretty good, but things like latin hypercubes are popular too.

Comment: @JohnMadden I will not have access to the ranges of input parameters in all cases. But I will have access to the produced model prediction output. Do you have any references at hand where I can read up about surrogate models and how they are used in ML?

Comment: Life is harder if we can't say anything about the possible range of inputs. My favorite book on surrogates: https://bobby.gramacy.com/surrogates/surrogates.pdf .

Comment: Thank you John, appreciate the help! :)